# How to use Kerberos ticket on another machine

Tags: java, kerberos

I have machineA and machineB. 
From machineA,  i use Java module KerberosTicket to get the credentials of the logged in user. eg

```
....
KerberosTicket ticket = (KerberosTicket)privatePrincipal;
return ticket.getEncoded();
....
```

Then I bring ticket over to machineB. How can I use Java to verify that this ticket is belong to valid user/principal? Is there sample code to do this?

I have search the web seems like using JAAS is one way. it means I somehow have to create a krb5cc file from ticket.getEncoded() and pass as a parameter for USeTicketCache. However, are there other alternative ways without having to create a physical file?

Is there a way to retrieve the "password" stored inside the ticket?
thanks

Comment: It seems like you're missing a basic understanding of how kerberos works. There is no password in the ticket and there isn't even any thing like a password in the basic kerberos ticket. Maybe it's a language problem, but I can't figure even where to start to try and answer your question. If you're using the API's correctly you shouldn't have to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not JAAS proficient, but have a good understanding of the krb5 protocol, there is no way to retrieve the password from the kerberos ticket (TGT) as the internally the libraries does string2key() of the password, before verifying the user credentials and caching it. Also if your password is retrievable from the krb5 ticket, its not longer safe on the wire.